# use values of two fields of a first SELECT into a second one

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Let's say we have a database with a table defined by the following fields:

```
id -- localCode -- localNumber -- status
```

Hoping to help you: there will be different records with the same combination (localCode + localNumber) but different status.

I would like to use the results from this query

```
SELECT localCode, localNumber FROM Table WHERE status = 'val_1'
```

to find the records with the combination (localCode + localNumber) found before but status = 'val_2'.

Thank you all

Comment: In addition to describing your problem, show sample data and your expected results, along with code you have tried.

Comment: You are partly right. I agree with you about adding sample data and expected results (I used to do this in other questions) but in this case it seemed to me I presented the problem in a clear schematic way (and in fact the answer is perfect for my problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a self-join on the table.

```
SELECT 
  t2.id 
FROM Table t1
INNER JOIN Table t2
  ON t1.localCode = t2.localCode
  AND t1.localNumber = t2.localNumber
WHERE t1.status = 'val_1'
  AND t2.status = 'val_2'
```

This query will find all IDs of records that have status `val_2` and where a corresponding entry with status `val_1` exists.